# How can I transfer all Chrome extensions and their settings for one macOS system to another macOS system?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I’m trying to move a Chrome installation I have from one macOS system to another. This Chrome installation has several extensions installed, and they contain a lot of settings and user data that I really need to transfer to the new system. So far I can’t get them to transfer at all.

I’ve tried copying these folders from the old user account to the new one:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome
~/Library/Preferences/com.google.Chrome.plist
~/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome
```

This worked for the application-wide settings, bookmarks, and such. But no extensions are transferred. In fact, when I check the contents of `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions` after launching Chrome, I see that it actually deletes all the extensions in this folder!

All of the internet searches I’ve done suggest copying those folders ought to do the trick. People have reported that it works in Windows. I have no idea why it’s not working for me.

It’s really important that these extensions transfer over because it would take me hours to set them all up again, and even then I would lose all of the data they’ve accumulated over the years. Help!